# Proof of logic gates

Tags: digital-logic

I have to prove:A’B’C’P+A’B’CP+ A’BC’P+ A’BCP’+ A’BCP+ AB’C’P+ 
                AB’CP’+ AB’CP+ ABC’P+ ABCP’+ ABCP = P + BC+AC

I have done this: P(A’B’C’+ABC+ A’B’C+ ABC’+ A’BC’+ AB’C+ A’BC+ 
   AB’C’)+ A’BCP’+ AB’CP’+ ABCP’

p + A’BCP’+ AB’CP’+ ABCP’ 
I don't know what to do further to prove

Comment: Another useful search term : Karnaugh map

Comment: Ya. i know karnaugh map, but i am not allowed to use it, i have to use it using the boolean algebra formulae

Comment: That's a bit slower but works as well. This is the second utterly basic homework question you've asked this morning : not really what the site is for.

Comment: if P = 1 you can disregard the rest of the formula. If P = 0 the sum of the triple ABC parts becomes interesting. => P + A’BCP’+ AB’CP’+ ABCP’ = P + (A’BC+ AB’C+ ABC)P’ = P + (A’BC+ AB’C+ ABC). Now simplify the part between parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this one .... P + A’BCP’+ AB’CP’+ ABCP’ below are the further step to solve it:

= P + P'(A'BC+AB'C+ABC)
= P + P'( A'BC+ ABC+ AB'C)
= P + P' ( (A'+A)BC + AB'C)
= P+ P' (BC +AB'C)
= P + P' ( C(B+AB'))
=  P + P' ( C(B+A)(B+B'))   // [AS WE KNOW X+YZ= (X+Y).(X+Z)]//

= P + P' ( C(B+A) )
= (P +P'). (P+ (C(B+A)) )   //[AGAIN USE  X+YZ= (X+Y).(X+Z)] //

= P + BC + AC

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's an approach using Boolean logic and no Karnaugh map.

1. The LHS includes a set A of minterms, but not all of them.
2. You can easily write out the set B of every minterm NOT in the LHS.
3. The RHS is a relatively simple Boolean expression.
4. Prove that every minterm in set A (the LHS) is included in the RHS.
5. Prove that every minterm in set B is NOT included in the RHS.

Having proved that everything in the LHS is in the RHS, and everything NOT in the LHS is NOT in the RHS, you have proved the LHS and RHS are identical.

Answer (score -1):

We can solve it easily Using K-map.... K-map of this boolean expression is shown below.
and this booolean expression corresponding to P+BC+AC
[image]

Comment: ya, i solved it through kmap and got this result. But i can't solve it through boolean laws

Comment: The OP _specifically stated_ that using a Karnaugh map was not allowed and that the solution needed to be based on Boolean algebra.